# Calculate range and exclude some text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate data from Sheet1 onto Sheet2.  Part of my calculation, I need to work out how many tasks I have within a 5-10 day deadline (which I can get from Column A{A1:A501}) but I also need it to exclude the tasks that have the word PINK which is in a separate Column C{C1:C501}. 
The calculation I have so far is:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A501,"<="&10)-COUNTIF(Sheet1!A1:A501,"<"&5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A1:A501,">=5",Sheet1!A1:A501,"<=10",Sheet1!C1:C501,"<>pink")
```

Comment: Hi Thanks,  it didn't work, it keeps bringing up a 0 value

Comment: It will return 0 when there is no cell in the A-column range with a value between 5 and 10 that coincides with a value from the C-column (same row) that is "pink".

Comment: I think that the OP meant to *"to exclude the tasks that have the word PINK"*. The finished formula will likely end up being `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A1:A501, ">=5", Sheet1!A1:A501, "<=10", Sheet1!C1:C501, "<>*pink*")` or `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A1:A501, ">="&today()+5, Sheet1!A1:A501, "<="&today()+10, Sheet1!C1:C501, "<>*pink*")`.